# WordPress SQL select column twice for different values

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm currently struggling to grab information from 1 column multiple times with a set of criteria and then using the information in a for-each loop to output the 2 different results.

The desired result is getting all results where the column `meta_key` has **billing_field_739** and **billing_field_267** as its value so that I can output `meta_value` in a for-each loop with their values.

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("

SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_wc_order_stats on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_wc_order_stats.order_id
WHERE meta_key = 'billing_field_739'
AND meta_key ='billing_field_267'
AND `date_created` >= CAST('2022-01-01' AS DATE) AND `date_created` <= CAST('2022-05-01' AS DATE)")

foreach($result as $row ) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row->meta_value;?></td> -- This is billing_field_739
      <td><?php echo $row->meta_value;?></td> -- This is billing_field_267
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Simply `WHERE meta_key IN ('billing_field_739', 'billing_field_267') ...`?

Comment: Thanks @jarlh - I just still have the issue that I get the results now but there is multiple different values in $row->meta_value and I need to get specific values out - I guess an IF statement could solve that?

Comment: Show us some sample table data, the current result and the wanted result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.)